# Apache: Prevent website (DNS) to be served by default website

Tags: apache-2.4

I have a bunch of DNS records that point to a server (IP). For each website I want to configure I use VirtualHost withe ServerName. But not all DNS should be answered by Apache (by its first alphanumerical website found)

My Question.
Is there some way, to say to Apache, ok serve only this DNSs. ??

Comment: Would you like to clarify what you want it's hard to tell. Also I can't believer that whatever your requirement is we don't already have an answer to it if you search / browse the relevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# [ Server Domain ]
ServerName your.domain.com
# [ Server Root ]
DocumentRoot /var/www/
</VirtualHost>
```

only the requests from your.domain.com will access to the website in /var/www/

and you can do it for each website on the same computer (and same ip for example)

like :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# [ Server Domain ]
ServerName your1.domain.com
# [ Server Root ]
DocumentRoot /var/www1/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
# [ Server Domain ]
ServerName your2.domain.com
# [ Server Root ]
DocumentRoot /var/www2/
</VirtualHost>
```

etc ...

Comment: Well, thats what I have right now, the problem is that everything that points to the server will be resolved by its first alphanumerical website found, all my DNS are in same domain.

I mean what I need is to know if there is and which configuration will tell apache to server ONLY to the ServerName(s) configs.

Because in your example the configuration does not prevent that, a request for  your32321.domain.com would be resolved by  you.domain.com  (obviouly if the DNS points to the IPs Apache is listening through)

Anyway thanks for your comment :)

Comment: i am not sure to understand your request can you put an exemple of what you exactly mean ?

Comment: yeap

Lets say you have nest
`code`
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName website1.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www1/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName website2.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www2/
</VirtualHost>
`code`

in the above configurations you don't have anything that is for website3.domain.com, so if you don't configure anything for it. and it points to the apache server, Apache will resolve website3 with website1 respond (due to its first alphanumerical website found).
I want Apache not to do that.

Comment: apache will display site for configured domain, if domain is not in the list it will display a 404 pages. If not that mean you got other configuration like servernae IP or servername localhost who is acting, maybe you should post your apache configuration, cause what i posted will work in your case (i just tested it on my own server)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot paste it, due to my company policies, I already grep for localhost or the IP with the ServerName directive in my directories and its not in my configs.

And my issue happens because it is a capability of Apache to resolve with a default website, I mean it s a behavior apache has, the 404 happens when the files you are trying to reach either not exist or the user running apache does not have read access for them.

Comment: do you have in each virtualhost a ServerName & Document root ?

Comment: Yes, for eash VirtualHost I have my own configs, and and if the DNS is not  in the configs, I dont want apache to resolve them with the first it finds ..

Comment: you seems to have an missconfiguration somewhere, cause it should not do it, check your redirect & rewrite rules